# How to keep running the code in main file after calling the function to get input value from user in R programming

Tags: r

I have 2 files:
1. sub file: get_input_template.R : this file contains the function to get input from user.

```
####################################
fun <- function(){
  x <- readline("What is the value of x?")  
  x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))
  return(x)
}
####################################
```

1. main.R: this file is main function and it will:
   step 1: call the 1st file to ask user input value and assign that value to variable n.
   step 2: continue doing something in my main program. Let's take simple task, for e.g, print out the value of n.

Here is my program:

```
####################################
source("get_input_template.R")
n<-fun()
sprintf("input value n = %s",n)
####################################
```

The problem is that when I run my main program fully, it shows an error since it doesn't stop at the 2nd line n<-fun() for user to input value. Therefore, i got an error:

```
---------------------------
Warning message:
In fun() : NAs introduced by coercion
---------------------------
```

How can I say R to stop running at 2nd line, and allow user to input data, and then print that input into the console. I know that I can fix it by moving sprintf("input value n = %s",n) into the subfile,but, it's not the way I want. How can i do it if I want **to keep that line of code in the main file only?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the way `R` parse and interpret your code, to make it simpler what happens is the same that

```
> source("get_input_template.R") # you run this
> n<-fun()                       # then this
What is the value of x?          # this appears and instead of giving the value you run
sprintf("input value n = %s",n)  #  you run this final line
```

if add `print(x)` just after `readline` you can see this

```
> source("UI/read console.R")
>   n<-fun()
What is the value of x?  sprintf("input value n = %s",n) # at this point R pauses and it is provided with "sprintf("input value n = %s",n)" as value of x
[1] "sprintf(\"input value n = %s\",n)"
Warning message:
In fun() : NAs introduced by coercion
```

You can solve this by wrapping your code in a function

```
f <- function(){
  source("UI/read console.R")
  n<-fun()
  sprintf("input value n = %s",n)
}
```

and then just running:

```
f()
```

The reason why it make different is that running a bunch of lines `R` executes them one by one, as soon as one statement finishes the following is run (and in your issue the third line is provided as input to the second :) ). In a function this doesn't happen, all the code in it is like part of one single statement (the function itself) so, when R is asking you to type something, the following line won't be executed.

Comment: @ThuyNguyenHong you are more than welcome honey.. All the best with your program! Cheers ;-)